# Transaction check error due to conflicting python versions during packstack install of OpenStack-Train

Tags: python, openstack, yum, novnc, websockify

The packstack installation of openstack is failing with the following error -

```
/Stage[main]/Nova::Vncproxy/Nova::Generic_service[vncproxy]/Package[nova-vncproxy]/ensure: change from 'purged' to 'present' failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install openstack-nova-novncproxy' returned 1: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/websockify from install of python2-websockify-0.8.0-13.el7.noarch conflicts with file from package python3-websockify-0.10.0-3.el8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/websockify.1.gz from install of python2-websockify-0.8.0-13.el7.noarch conflicts with file from package python3-websockify-0.10.0-3.el8.noarch
```

Above you can see that two files (/usr/bin/websockify & /usr/share/man/man1/websockify.1.gz) are conflicting between python2-websockify & python3-websockify & so any one of them has to be removed but,

while checking the installed packages of the system I can see that **python2-websockify** is only available in the system but **not** installed in the system.

```
[root@controller ~]# yum list | grep -i python2-web
python2-webob.noarch                     1.8.5-1.el7                   @centos-ceph-nautilus
python2-websocket-client.noarch          0.54.0-1.el7                  centos-ceph-nautilus
python2-websockify.noarch                0.8.0-13.el7                  centos-openstack-train

[root@controller ~]# yum list installed | grep -i python2-web
python2-webob.noarch              1.8.5-1.el7            @centos-ceph-nautilus
```

However **python3-websockify** is installed in the system & I cannot remove it because the nova-novnc package has a dependency on that one.

```
[root@controller ~]# yum list installed | grep -i python3-web
python3-websockify.noarch         0.10.0-3.el8           @/python3-websockify-0.10.0-3.el8.noarch
```

Now, how can I remove the **python2-websockify.noarch** which is not even installed on the system?
& when it is not installed then why the error is mentioning

```
from install of python2-websockify-0.8.0-13.el7.noarch conflicts with file from package python3-websockify-0.10.0-3.el8.noarch
```

I tried to delete the python2-websockify but as it is not installed so giving following messages -

```
[root@controller ~]# yum remove python2-websockify-0.8.0-13.el7.noarch
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No Match for argument: python2-websockify-0.8.0-13.el7.noarch
No Packages marked for removal
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with packstack, but openstack version Train is quite old and EOL, I'd recommend to install a newer openstack version (based on python3 instead python2).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after removing the epel-release because the puppet was coming updated from Epel instead of packstack

#yum autoremove epel-release